# ios5 ios6 and Twitter integration

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

- I'm working on an iOS app compatible with iOS5 and iOS6 (iPhone only application)
- I develop using XCODE 4.5 (4G182)
- the app need to post Tweets on Twitter
- for the ios6 implementation I'm using with success the UIActivityViewController class
- for the ios5 implementation I'm using the TWTweetComposeViewController  from the Twitter.framework, I'm using the following code (already used and working in previous applications I developed with previous XCODE versions)

  ```
      TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
      tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
          [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      };

      NSString *textToShare = @"Tweet Example";
      [tweetSheet setInitialText:textToShare];
      [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
  ```

this code present the standard Twitter panel, but after I press the send button I receive an alert with the following message:

**Cannot Send Tweet**

**The tweet, "Tweet Example" cannot be sent because the connection to Twitter failed.**

**[Cancel] [Try Again]**

I tried to compile also the Apple Sample application "Tweetie"
and I get the same result on ios5 iPhones, I tested it on a first generation iPad (ios5.1)
and it seems to work fine

does somebody has the same problem? 
do you have an suggestions about it?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

solved

- I uninstalled the twitter applcation form the iPhone I was testing on
- Removed the Twitter account form the Settings
- Installed again Twitter
- newly logged in twitter from the Settings

then everything worked again fine

Comment: You might also try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+tweet+cannot+be+sent+because+the+connection+to+Twitter+failed.) first next time.

Comment: Handle this error as it's common a user doesn't have Twitter account set on device. This is a normal flow of your app too!

Comment: If you solved your problem, mark this answer as correct, so this question doesn't appear in the unanswered lists.

Comment: @BryanH when you write a comment like that, remember that it's entirely likely that it will be one of the first things someone googling in the future will find.